# Why these factor added? Is this a formula

Tags: integration

I wonder why these factors are added? And what is that λ symbol?
$$\frac{x^4+4x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}dx
=ǭ_3 (x) \sqrt{x^2+4}+λ\int \frac{dx} {\sqrt{x^2+4}} dx
and then
=(Ax^3+Bx^2...$$
So what is it?
[Please check out the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvIIy.jpg)

Comment: This is hard to read.

Comment: @lulu this is the integration of an irrational expression

Comment: And what does $ǭ_3 (x)$ mean?  And why is there no integration indicated on the left?

Comment: [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate+%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E4%2B4x%5E2%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Bx%5E2%2B4%7D%7Ddx) is the integration you want (I think).  I'm not clear what your goal is.  If you ultimately want a power series, I'd start by converting the integrand to a power series.

Comment: Q3 is part of the formula and it is replaced by ax^3+bx^2+cx+d, it is thrown right side of equation and take derivative of it. And the book finds A B C and D and replace them in the formula. I wonder(my goal) what formula is it?

Comment: This doesn’t make any sense. You need to offer more details.

Comment: As far as I can understand,the solution seems to simplify $\frac{x^4+4x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}$ to  ${x^2.\sqrt{x^2+4}}$ after which integration by parts is used.